# Delphi:How to clear hashtable 's value in TGpStringHash-close

Tags: delphi, hashtable

The Only way is let [TGpStringHash](http://code.google.com/p/gpdelphiunits/source/browse/trunk/src/GpStringHash.pas) free.Then re-create it?

Answer (score 1):

TGpStringHas has no Delete or Clear method so the only way is indeed to destroy and recreate the instance.